# How do I drill down into a JSON object using Ruby's JSON gem

Tags: ruby, json

I have some JSON returned from Google Maps API.

```
{"results"=>
  [{"address_components"=>
 [{"long_name"=>"1600", "short_name"=>"1600", "types"=>["street_number"]},
  {"long_name"=>"President's Park",
   "short_name"=>"President's Park",
   "types"=>["establishment"]},
  {"long_name"=>"Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest",
   "short_name"=>"Pennsylvania Ave NW",
   "types"=>["route"]},
  {"long_name"=>"Washington",
   "short_name"=>"Washington",
   "types"=>["locality", "political"]},
  {"long_name"=>"District of Columbia",
   "short_name"=>"DC",
   "types"=>["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]},
  {"long_name"=>"United States",
   "short_name"=>"US",
   "types"=>["country", "political"]},
  {"long_name"=>"20500", "short_name"=>"20500", "types"=>["postal_code"]}],
"formatted_address"=>
 "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest, President's Park, Washington, DC 20500, USA",
"geometry"=>
 {"location"=>{"lat"=>38.8977332, "lng"=>-77.0365305},
  "location_type"=>"ROOFTOP",
  "viewport"=>
   {"northeast"=>{"lat"=>38.8990821802915, "lng"=>-77.0351815197085},
    "southwest"=>{"lat"=>38.8963842197085, "lng"=>-77.03787948029151}}},
"partial_match"=>true,
"types"=>["street_address"]}],
 "status"=>"OK"}
```

I'm trying to access the latitude and longitude like so:

```
parsed = JSON.parse(data)
p parsed["results"]["location"]["lat"]
p parsed["results"]["location"]["lng"]
```

When I do so, my code throws and error: "no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError).

I will be very grateful to anyone who can shed some light onto my problem.  Thank you.

Comment: parsed["results"] is an array so you can't index it with a string, you have to use an integer.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all of this. Could you perhaps post a small example?

Comment: Type `parsed["results"].class` and see what you get.  Then type `parsed["results"][0]`.  If you're feeling adventurous, try `parsed["results"][99]`.

Comment: And then you should probably find a Ruby tutorial that explains what arrays and hashes are and how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in your case it would be

```
p parsed["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]
# => {"lat"=>38.8977332, "lng"=>-77.0365305}
```